# Is it haram to for a sister and her brother to sit together, when both are no longer children?

Tags: sharia, hadith, practical-islam, source-identification, fatwa

Is it a sin for a brother (16 years old) and  his elder sister (18 years old) to sit near to each other? Is there a hadith regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not a sin, as they are not suitable to marry each other.

Here is a quote from the Quran indicating that women do not have to cover themselves around their brothers:

> And tell the believing women to reduce [some] of their vision and
>   guard their private parts and not expose their adornment except that
>   which [necessarily] appears thereof and to wrap [a portion of] their
>   headcovers over their chests and not expose their adornment except to
>   their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons,
>   their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their
>   sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands possess, or
>   those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are
>   not yet aware of the private aspects of women. And let them not stamp
>   their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment. And
>   turn to Allah in repentance, all of you, O believers, that you might
>   succeed.
>
> Surat An-Nūr 24:31

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE, please provide answers with valid explanations and authentic references